# Entity Framework - "cannot insert duplicate object" for child model

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm sure there is a very simple solution for this. Using EntityFramework, given these three models:

```
public class Player {
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Team Team {get; set;}
}

public class Team {
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Sponsor {
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public Player Representative {get; set;}
}
```

And corresponding sets in the context:

```
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sponsor> Sponsors { get; set; }
```

The problem comes when adding a new Player when the Team already exists.

Only adding a new Player works fine:

```
  // player is a new Player
  using (var db = new MyContext())
  {
       db.Players.AddOrUpdate(player);
       db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

But trying to change the Representative property on an existing Sponsor fails:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
     var sponsor = db.Sponsors.Single(s => s.Id == 1);
     sponsor.Representative = player;
     db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This fails with the error:

{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Teams'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Teams'."}

I don't want it to duplicate the Team entry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework disconnected graph and navigation property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026542/entity-framework-disconnected-graph-and-navigation-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a [known bug](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2128) in `AddOrUpdate`. A work-around is to replace the `player` reference to the object that is actually tracked by EF:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
     db.Players.AddOrUpdate(player);
     db.SaveChanges();

     // Get the actually tracked player:
     player = db.Players.Local.Single(p => p.Id == player.Id);
}
```

In your current code, when you do ...

```
sponsor.Representative = player;
```

... EF "thinks" you're adding a new player because it doesn't track the object `player` is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in your error you are trying to add multiple Teams object with the same **ID** that way you are getting this error, make primary key auto increment your problem will be solved.